# Como rellenar una matriz de forma correcta

Tags: python

"Tengo esta matriz y la quiero rellenar con 1 y 2, si los resultados son diferentes se rellenan la siguiente columna hacia la derecha desde la posicion 0, y si los resultados se repiten la matriz se rellena en la misma columna por ejemplo : si estos son los resultados: 1,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,1,2,1,1
la matriz seria:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi solucion me sale
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si notas, la posicion [1][3] es 0 cuando quiero que sea 2 al igual que la [1][4].

```
import numpy as np

tablero = np.zeros((10,10))
print(tablero)
z=0
row=0
col=0
p = 0
q = 0
lista_resultado = list()

while z < 20:

    resultado = int(input("Dame un resultado 1 o 2"))
    lista_resultado.append(resultado)
    print(lista_resultado)
    print("el ultimo",lista_resultado[-1])
    if len(lista_resultado) > 1:
        print("el penultimo", lista_resultado[len(lista_resultado)-2])

    if len(lista_resultado) == 1:
       tablero[row][col] = resultado
         print(tablero)

    if len(lista_resultado) > 1:
        if lista_resultado[-1] != lista_resultado[len(lista_resultado) - 2]:
          p= p+1
          print("cuantos cambios:", p)
          for x in range(10):
             if x == 0:
                 tablero[0][col+1] = resultado
          print(tablero)
          col = 1 + col

    if len(lista_resultado) > 1:
        if lista_resultado[-1] == lista_resultado[len(lista_resultado) - 2]:
            #for y in range(10):
                if tablero[row+1][col] == 0:
         #           for y in range(10):

                    tablero[row+1][col] = resultado
                row = row + 1
                print(tablero)
    #       row = row + 1
    z=z+1
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Si no pones el lenguaje, nadie sabe de que estas hablando...

Answer (score 1):

No entiendo muy bien qué hace el código que pones, pero para desplazarse en ese arreglo como lo describes, solo hay que tener en cuenta las siguientes condiciones:

(1) En la posición de partida: `row = 0`, `col = 0`

(2) Si el número es diferente al anterior: se desplaza a la derecha: `col += 1`, y se reinicia la fila: `row = 0`

(3) Si el número es igual al anterior: se desplaza hacia abajo: `row += 1` y la columna se mantiene `col = col`.

Con eso se puede escribir un código:

```py
import numpy as np

width  = 10
height = 10
tablero = np.zeros((width, height))
print(tablero)
row = 0
col = 0
temp = 0

while row < width-1 and col < height-1:
    resultado = input("Dame un resultado 1 o 2: ")
    if resultado not in ['1', '2']:
        print("Dato no valido, reintente")
        continue
    resultado = int(resultado)
    if temp == 0: # (1) Condicion inicial
        pass
    elif resultado != temp: # (2) Desplazamiento a la derecha
        row = 0
        col += 1
    else: # (3) Desplazamiento hacia abajo
        row += 1
    tablero[row][col] = resultado
    temp = resultado
    print(tablero) # <-- Comentar para dejar de ver en tiempo real

print('Tablero Final')
print(tablero)
```